# Redirect - IPtables

Tags: iptables

I'm going to be redirected to page `192.168.1.1` When the user enters the `www.google.com` site.

So I run the following commands on the router :

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80
```

But it does not work properly.

When the user enters the **Yahoo** site, it is redirected to page `192.168.1.1`
But when the user enters the **Google** site, they are not redirected to page `192.168.1.1`

Also, when the user enters the `connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204` site :

> Not Found
>  the requested url /generate_204 was not found on this
>   server

**Why ?**

Answer (score 1):

These iptables rules are forwarding ports 80 and 443 to 192.168.1.1, which is ALL websites. Not just google.com.

IPTables is the wrong tool for this. You're going to want to use a proxy such as [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)

Alternatively, if you're just wanting to redirect websites on the local machine, you could use the hosts file (/etc/hosts), but that will redirect ALL users.